# How to preserve number of decimal places in perl after multiplication

Tags: perl

I have one floating point number in Perl and after multiplying with negative integer, all trailing zeroes are getting removed automatically. However I still need those extra zeroes.

Example:

```
my $float = 1.40000;
my $multiply = -1 * $float;
print "Negative number: $multiply"; //-1.4
```

Is there any way to get `-1.40000`?

Comment: Floating numbers are not represented exactly, it has to do with how they are stored in memory. If you want to preserve the zeroes exactly, use a string. E.g. `my $float = "-1.40000`.

Comment: There's no decimal place to *preserve*. A floating point number is stored as `1.<53 binary digits> * 2^<exponent>` (1.011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011 * 2^0, in this case. Yup, 4/10 is periodic in binary just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your output using `printf`.

```
printf( "Negative number: %.4f\n", $multiply );
```

Learn more about `printf` with `perldoc -f printf` or [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf).

Comment: Perhaps add a blurb about `sprintf()` so the number can be retained intact for future operations as well? `my $num = sprintf("%.4f", -1 * $float);`

Comment: @stevieb Technically, the number does not change internally at all when using either operation. Only when it is printed is the lack of zeroes apparent, and only when it is printed is it relevant. So no, `sprintf` is not relevant to the question.